# Qt 4.7.0 static build for wince

Tags: qt, qt4

I can't do a static build of Qt 4.7.0 for WinCE.

First I copied Qt 4.7.0 wince sources to `C:\Qt\4.7.0_wince` and ran a configure with params

`-platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wincewm60professional-msvc2008`

Then `setcepath.bat` for wincewm60professional-msvc2008 and then `nmake`. Everything was alright.

Now I need to do a static version of Qt's libs. How should I do this? I created another Qtdir with the same sources of Qt 4.7.0 wince in `C:\Qt\4.7.0_wince_static` and ran a configure with params

```
-release -nomake examples -nomake demos -no-qt3support -no-openssl -no-opengl -no-webkit -no-style-motif -no-style-cde -no-style-cleanlooks -no-style-plastique -no-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008 -xplatform wincewm60professional-msvc2008 -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-gif -static
```

Then `setcepaths.bat` for wincewm60professional-msvc2008. But when I ran `nmake` I got an error:

```
Generating Code...
link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.7.0_wince_static\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\4.7.0_wince
_static\lib" /NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDO
WSCE,5.02 /MACHINE:THUMB /OUT:..\..\bin\qmlviewer.exe @C:\Users\SerGe\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\nm315F.tmp
QtDeclarative.lib(qdeclarativevaluetype.obj) : warning LNK4217: locally defined
symbol ?qt_defaultDpi@@YAHXZ (int __cdecl qt_defaultDpi(void)) imported in funct
ion "public: float __cdecl QDeclarativeFontValueType::pointSize(void)const " (?p
ointSize@QDeclarativeFontValueType@@QBAMXZ)
QtGui.lib(jmemmgr.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol getenv refere
nced in function jinit_memory_mgr
..\..\bin\qmlviewer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\ce\bin\x86_arm\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

What's wrong? Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!!!